# LUIS does not finish training

Tags: azure-language-understanding

Added +1 Intent and utterances from suggestions to my intents.
After that, hit the train button. But Luis does not finishing training as usual.

> Training: 4/8 completed

And that's it. Luis does not move from this point.

How much time Luis takes to train for 10 Intents for example ?

I googled that but i didn't find anything about.

Does someone had this problem ?

Comment: What are the number of intents, entities, utterances, features, ... But in general try refreshing the page and retrain.

Comment: I also experienced the same thing, no explanation, I think it's an issue on Microsoft's end, I tend to go away for 30 mins, come back, refresh, retrain and it then works.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and figured it out that if entities are not mapped to the utterances properly then the application training will not finish. So you may need to verify the utterance which is not mapped to entities.

As at the time of train it's not visible which intent is having the issue. So I would suggest you, add intents one at a time and map its utterances to entities then train it. This way you will know which intents are working and causing the issue.

I hope the suggestion was helpful.

Thanks